# jQuery ajax check and submit form, always have to submit twice when ajax return nofound

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, triggers, submit

I have this ajax check to see if the name is found or nofound. It works fine when data returns found, but when it return nofound, I must submit it again to trigger it.

Does anyone have a suggestion or a better solution for this?

```
$('#formletter').submit(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();

    if ($.formLoading != false) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "submit_ajax_contents.php",
        data: "namecheck="+name,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'nofound'){
            $.formLoading = false;
            $('#formletter').submit();
            }else{
            alert('found');
            $.formLoading = true;
            }
        }
        });
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }

    });

});
```

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do a non-async ajax call: (I didn't test this code)

```
$('#formletter').submit(function(event) {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var found = false;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "submit_ajax_contents.php",
        data: "namecheck="+name,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'found')
                found = true;
        }
    });
    if (found)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Note that if the ajax call fails, it will assume `found` is `false` (i.e. the value won't be changed)

Comment: And, of course, you should give some indication to the user that the name check is being done, so the user doesn't freak out when a couple of seconds pass and nothing seems to have happened.

Comment: and yes, I'll put a indication of the name check.